# Is there a way to control the volume of an wav file when using EasySound in java?

Tags: java, audio, volume

My call to the sound looks like this, and I want to be able to change the volume of the sound.

```
EasySound soundOne = new EasySound("sound.wav");
soundOne.play();
```

Comment: It seems like that `EasySound` is not a well-known Java library. Can you please provide a reference to its origin?

Comment: It pops up if you google "Gary Litvin EasySound". It just provides the object EasySound that holds the object (wav file).

Comment: The search did not work for me. Almost all the entries pertained to some real estate broker. When asking for help, it is important to help people help you. Since you are new, I'm not going to vote this down, but am just letting you know that your question will likely get down votes because of neglecting to provide a URL to the resource that you have questions about.

Answer (score 0):

If the library doesn't provide dynamic volume control, you can try using a `FloatControl` as described in [Processing Audio with Controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html). Using this method, I've only had success with the MASTER_GAIN type. The problem with this control is that it affects all playing audio at the same time. I haven't found the other types listed to be consistently implemented for different systems.

For this to work, you might run into difficulties figuring out what port the library uses. The tutorial I linked has an earlier chapter, [Accessing Audio System Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html) which deals with inspecting your audio system.

There is another relatively simple audio library that has implemented dynamic volume: [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue-maven). Disclaimer: I am the author. It's Maven-based. If you don't know how to use a resource by linking via a Maven pom file, one option is to directly copy the five classes/interfaces into your program, editing the package line to match the file location where you place them. I'm currently working to figure out how to best set up github "Releases" with corresponding jar files, and haven't provided a jar that can be downloaded as of yet. The jar can be generated if you know [Maven basics](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/maven/maven-tutorial.html) and have forked and cloned the project.